# Change single value in URL string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am learning web scraping and I am practicing on example.webscraping.com.
I am able to pull the information that I want from a single page but I would like to know how to iterate over multiple pages in the simplest manner. I was taking the approach to just use a formatted string as the only difference between the pages is the value at the end of the URL "http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/1".

However, even by creating an integer and trying to input it as a string in the URL that has a counter on it as to change the url after every complete loop cycle I am not having any luck. I realize that may not be the universally accepted way of doing it but I do not know of any other way besides creating a dictionary and trying that but it seems like opening another can of worms.
Any advice is gladly accepted, I'm sorry if this has been discussed before but all of the posts I have found are slightly too complex for me to understand as a beginner.
Also, webloop is the function in which I use a for loop to pull all of the data I want from the site.
Thank you for your suggestions so far. For future reference if I wanted to look through a site like ebay and amazon with the same request and just change it after every loop, what is the best method of approach?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as smoothie
def webloop():
    for results in soup.find('div', id='results').find_all('div'):      
      country = results.a.text
      flag = results.a.img
      print (country)
      print(flag)
      print()

pagenum = 1

while pagenum != 4:
    source =requests.get('http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/pagenum=%s').text %(str(pagenum))
    soup = smoothie(source, 'html.parser')
    webloop()
    pagenum += 1
```

I intend for the loop to request a new page with every iteration but I am getting this error ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59) at index 2159

Comment: I think this is just a typo. You're trying to format the returned page, not the URL. Change it to `requests.get('http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/pagenum=%s' % (str(pagenum))).text`. The error is coming about because it seems like the page source has `%Y` somewhere in it, and `%` is interpreting that as a formatting character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is your issue, but the code in your question has your string formatting in the wrong place. And I have no idea what `webloop()` is here? Also, that webscraping example page seems to start its pagenumbers at `0`, not `1`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as smoothie

pagenum = 1

while pagenum != 4:
    source =requests.get('http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/pagenum={}'.format(pagenum))
    soup = smoothie(source.text, 'html.parser')
    webloop()
    pagenum += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the string formatting, with Python 3.6 you can use *f-strings* that are more readable

```
source = requests.get(f'http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/pagenum={pagenum}')
```

There are other problems, like `source.text` and not `source` and the missing (in the piece of code you have posted) `webloop()`function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as smoothie
import requests

for pagenum in range(1, 4):
    source = requests.get(f'http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/index/pagenum={pagenum}')
    soup = smoothie(source.text, 'html.parser')
    webloop()
```

Comment: the source.text was initially used  so that I could prettify the results and be able to read it a little easier(If I remember right). The webloop function is now included in my posted code, I hadnt included it at first because I did not think it was necessary. Also, I will look into f strings now, The only experience I have is the codeacademy python 2.6 training camp(I have no idea why I didnt do 3) and since I started coding on my own I switched to the newest version of python so I have not yet figured out what carried over and what was updated